# Create a 'grid' of timetable data from SQL (mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, grid, denormalization

I'm trying to work out how to create a grid which is a bit like a de-normalised table. I'm using MySQL and will render the data with PHP/HTML.

This is for an attendance monitoring tool we're piloting. It's slightly more complicated as we don't always get a record e.g. attendance not recorded for some reason (not Yes or No but ?? -'not sure/don't know')

```
As an example, we have attendance data for students. The data holds
1. User id (a unique identifier)
2. Course ID (unique identifier)
3. Date/time - actually week number so a discrete value (1,2,3,4 etc)
4. Attended Y/N (actually more detail)
5. Other date (timestamp, created by)
```

As an example the attendance table holds this

```
UserID CourseID Week Attended
jeff123 Chem101 32   Y
jeff123 Chem101 33   Y
jeff123 Chem101 34   Y
jeff123 Math101 35   Y
jeff123 Math101 32   Y
jeff123 Math101 33   Y
jeff123 Math101 34   N
jeff123 Chem101 35   Y
jane123 Chem101 32   Y
jane123 Chem101 33   N
jane123 Chem101 34   Y
jane123 Math101 35   Y
jane123 Math101 32   Y
jane123 Math101 33   Y
jane123 Math101 34   Y
jane123 Chem101 35   Y
...
...
```

And it doesn't hold a record where nothing was recorded; sorry if that sounds obvious but that's part of what I'm trying to work out.

Using PHP I could loop "downward" on through usernames and loop "to the right" for weeks to end up with a grid

```
Week      32  33 34 35 ....
User id   Y   Y  Y  N
jeff123   Y   N  N  Y
jane123  .....
...
```

....

This feels wrong as

```
1. I possibly need to do a sub query for each grid point as data may not exist
2. I keep thinking I need an outer join to fill in the missing data in the grid
3. If this was something like company and profit then a missing profit record could be added using an outer join showing Null or similar
4. As this is looking for a missing record for both userID and Week number then I'm wondering if I can do an outer join (but in more dimensions user and week)?
```

I could reduce the dimensions but doing a single row or column at a time.

I'm just wondering if there's a better solution? I can run an overnight job to create the grid so it doesn't have to be fast or live data.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks
Jason

Comment: where is the CourseID in the result  ?

Comment: It feels right to me.

Comment: You have the right idea. If you feel like you are missing information, gather it all up, put it in an array, then run your loops.

Comment: Good point -where is the course id! I'm certainly not planning a 3d grid*. I'll probably display by userid or by course id. I'm actually counting the number of attendances per week so each grid point will be a count plus link to display the detail (timestamps+course ids). The plan is to link this to our timetabling data but not there with that yet. *Actually that be a nice idea for a dta vis exercise but certainly not for this work. 

OK sounds like I'm not too far off.

Thanks all.
Jas